# What is the antagonist of epinephrine?

Tags: endocrinology

Norepinephrine and epinephrine have similar stimulant properties on the nervous system and the body. I was wondering which hormone is the antagonist of epinephrine?

Answer (score 4):

You should understand that it is not the neurotransmitter that is responsible for an effect; it is the neural network that causes an effect and the neurotransmitter is just a mediator.

In CNS, glutamate is generally used in excitatory synapses whereas GABA is chiefly used in inhibitory [synapses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synapse). Similarly, in peripheral nervous system epinephrine and acetylcholine are used in excitatory synapses whereas glycine is used in inhibitory synapses. Some neurotransmitters always cause excitation in the post-synaptic cell (for example glutamate), however, they can also cause activation of inhibitory neurons and thereby cause inactivation, indirectly. Also, the post-synaptic effect depends on the type of receptor expressed by the post synaptic cell and not the neurotransmitter *per-se*. For example, α-adrenergic receptors cause smooth muscle contraction whereas the β<sub>2</sub>- receptors cause smooth muscle relaxation <sup>[[1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2142449/)]</sup>. Similarly, there are both inhibitory and excitatory dopamine receptors <sup>[[2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/277093a0)]</sup>.

The two divisions of the autonomic nervous system — the [sympathetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sympathetic_nervous_system) and [parasympathetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasympathetic_nervous_system) systems act in a complementary manner. The former uses epinephrine and norepinephrine whereas the latter uses acetylcholine.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head +1